# Animated TV show of unique cars that fought robots

Tags: story-identification, tv, animated-series

I remember watching an animated show during my childhood(I was born 2004 so must've been around 2008-2014).

The main premise of the show was about a group of friends that each owned a unique cool car. And the show was sci-fi. With their cars they would fight against robots in different contests which used their cars.

I remember there was a 'restaurant' type place in the middle of a desert and one of the characters from the main group of friends was always there eating pizza.

I also remember one of the peoples' car had a front half that could flip/rotate (I think his car was red) around him while he stayed upright.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F!  Do you remember what channel you watched this on?  The animation style?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This sounds like [*Hot Wheels Battle Force 5*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hot_Wheels_Battle_Force_5). Humans racing against robotic adversaries in high tech vehicles in different areas over "Battle Keys." The show aired starting in 2009 as well.

[image: The heroes of "Hot Wheels Battle Force 5"]

Comment: Thank you so much! I kept trying to describe it in google but nothing was coming up. I'm surprised someone else remembers it as well. Thanks again